# a question about "ERROR: pip's dependency" for deep learning

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pip

all,

After I installed a package with "pip install keras-flops", I had the following message.

ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
googleapis-common-protos 1.59.1 requires protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0.dev0,>=3.19.5, but you have protobuf 3.20.0 which is incompatible.
tensorflow-metadata 1.13.1 requires protobuf<5,>=3.20.3, but you have protobuf 3.20.0 which is incompatible.

tensorboard 2.10.1 requires protobuf<3.20,>=3.9.2, but you have protobuf 3.20.0 which is incompatible.

tensorflow 2.10.1 requires protobuf<3.20,>=3.9.2, but you have protobuf 3.20.0 which is incompatible.

I can still run my deep learning codes. Do I need to fix the above problems?

Thanks

Erick

Answer (score 1):

**Keras-flops** is older package which was last released on : Aug 17, 2020 and only compatible with `tensorflow` and `keras version 2.2` with `python 3.6`. So installing this package in latest tensorflow version is causing the version incompatibility or pip dependency error. Please refer to this [keras-flops pypi](https://pypi.org/project/keras-flops/) link for more details.

You can alternatively try using Tensorflow Model's [try_count_flops](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tfm/core/train_utils/try_count_flops) in the latest Tensorflow version which is used to count and return model FLOPs.

Comment: Thanks. I can still run my codes, but I found the inference time is longer when I predict images by using the trained deep learning model. Is it related to the problem?

Comment: I solved the problem by downgrade the version of tensorflow.  The latest tensorflow does not support GPU card with windows system. (This cause the inference time is much longer because it is run on CPU, not GPU)